# SQL-query help needed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I guess my first question was not really clear so here is it again.

I wrote a query that does not select the last five rows in my dataset:

```
with query AS
(select ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY SchemaName, TableName order by StartTime desc) AS num,
from logging.ImportLogging_MSH)
Select
from query
where num > 5 and SchemaName = 'opps' and TableName = 'vs4_status_history_address'
```

I want to extend my query so that it checks if any of the last five rows in EndTime has a NULL value, then the query skips that row, I do not however want to remove all null values in my Endtime.

My idea was to create an integer variable that gets incremented if EndTime has a null value
e.g. in java it'll usually be like this:

```
int x = 5;

if (EndTime == null) {
x++;
}
```

so I tried to add this to my query which is not correct:

```
declare @n INT = 5
with query AS
(select ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY SchemaName, TableName order by StartTime desc) AS num,
from logging.ImportLogging_MSH)
Select ,
case when EndTime is null then @n = @n + 1 end
from query
where num > n and SchemaName = 'opps' and TableName = 'vs4_status_history_address'
```

It's an assignment from my new student job and I don't want to ask around a lot on my first day so if you guys have any suggestions it'll help me a lot :)

[both queries with and without the last 5 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKNiv.png)

The desired result I'm trying to get but this problem with this approach is that all NULL values in EndTime are removed, which I should that do

```
with query AS
(select ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY SchemaName, TableName order by StartTime desc) AS num, *
from logging.ImportLogging_MSH
where EndTime is not null)
Select *
from query
where num > 5 and SchemaName = 'opps' and TableName = 'vs4_status_history_address'


select * 
from logging.ImportLogging_MSH
where SchemaName = 'opps' and TableName = 'vs4_status_history_address'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im41u.png)

as you can see here, the last four rows that contain null values in EndTime are removed and the next last 5 rows are not selected

I'm trying to write this same query but without removing all null values off Endtime

The answer I'm getting when writing Steve's query

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUSWk.png)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server

Comment: Honestly - get into the GOOD habit of ordering your resultsets generally. Here it is a REQUIREMENT to see your sample data (as images - another bad problem) in the appropriate order. Don't assume that what you see is accurate without an ORDER BY clause since your question is highly dependent on "order". _I don't want to ask around a lot on my first day_ But it is expected that new employees do that. Not doing that is poor judgement on your part.